# c# udp client server in same app filtering out data sent from local app

Tags: c#, udp

I have a client server application that both listen and sends on the same multicast address/port. The problem is that I will receive loopback on data sent.

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 62255);

client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;

client.Client.Bind(localEp);

IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.10.4.1");
client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);
IPEndPoint remoteep = new IPEndPoint(multicastaddress, 62255);

while (true)
{
    Byte[] buffer = client.Receive(ref localEp);

    string msgString = "test";
    byte[] buffer2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msgString);
    client.Send(buffer2, buffer2.Length, remoteep);
}
```

I have tried to use `localEp.Address.ToString()` to filter out what is sent from the local app, but when I tried on one computer with several `NIC` I still got local messages. Any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a different port number for each direction.  Right now you are using 62255 for both directions.  Use 62256 for other direction.

Comment: I would like to have the same adress and port since if there is more than two instances that would fail, right?

Comment: Only fail if same IP and PORT.  You could filter by checking the remote end point on the receive message and ignore ones that came have local IP.

Comment: Then i guess I would have to get an array of internal ips to check against?

Comment: Windows a PC only has one IP address.  Some network cards support multiple IP addresses with each IP being in a separate sub-net.  In this case you are sending to a broadcast multicast IP address.  Multicast normally stays in one sub-net so you would not get the same multicast from multiple cards (multiple IP).  You would register to listen only on the sub-net where you expect the multicast to be located.